# ¿Cómo crear arreglo de tablas MySQL?

Tags: mysql

A ver, quizá ni la pregunta esté bien formulada, pero es la única forma que asocio.
La duda, con un ejemplo:
Si quiero hacer una receta y está compuesta por varios **Ingredientes** (otra tabla con sus respectivos atributos) ¿Cómo hago? Ojo : la cantidad de ingredientes puede variar.

Comment: ¿Estás diseñando la base de datos? Si es así, tienes que incluir lo que intentaste hacer y el problema con ese diseño. Ya vendrán a decirte que la idea no es resolver deberes ajenos :)

Comment: no hay arreglos.. hay tablas, conectadas a otras tablas con claves.. tu pregunta es basicamente sobre diseño de base de datos, lee sobre eso...

Comment: Deberías pasar por la sección [ask] y realizar el [tour]

Answer (score 1):

Lo ideal en este caso seria que tuvieras las tablas

```
ingredientes =>
  id,
  nombre

receta =>
  id,
  nombre

lista_ingredientes =>
  id,
  ingrediente_id,
  tipo_medicion_id,
  cantidad,
  receta_id

tipo_medicion =>
  id,
  nombre(ejemplo: gramos, ml, etc)
```

Y asi tendrias un relacion entre las tablas sin tener que utilizar malas practicas. Fuera de eso podrias no hacer eso y hacer las consultas directamente como tu mencionas para obtener los atributos especificos de las tablas especificas como lo siguiente

```
     SELECT nombre_receta, (SELECT nombre_ingrediente FROM Ingredientes WHERE id = X) AS nombre_ingrediente FROM Recetas WHERE id = X
```

y asi sucesivamente.